# PHP Constructor no funciona

Tags: php, poo, pdo

tengo un problema con un constructo en php, tengo mi clase conexion:

```
    <?php

   
class Conexion{
    private $host='localhost:3306';
    private $user='root';
    private $password='1234';
    private $db='videojuegos';
    private $conexion;

    public function __construct(){
        $connectionString="mysql:host=$this->host; dbname=$this->db; charset=utf8";
        try{
            $this->conexion=new PDO($connectionString,$this->user,$this->password);
            $this->conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $this->conexion='Error de conexion';
            echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function connect(){
        return $this->conexion;
    }
}


?>
```

y tengo otro archivo que esta asi:

```
<?php 
include "../clases/conexion.php";


class OperVideojuegos extends Conexion{
    private $strnombre;
    private $strdescripcion;
    private $con;
    

    public function __construstc(){
        $this->con=new Conexion();
        $this->con=$this->con->connect();
    }

    public function getVideojuegos(){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM videojuegos";
        $execute=$this->con->query($sql);
        $request=$execute->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($request);

    }

}

$obj=new OperVideojuegos();
$obj->getVideojuegos();




?>
```

cuando yo lo pruebo me da el siguiente error :

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendiendo\APIS\API_Videojuego\operDB\OperVideojuegos.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendiendo\APIS\API_Videojuego\operDB\OperVideojuegos.php(27): OperVideojuegos->getVideojuegos() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aprendiendo\APIS\API_Videojuego\operDB\OperVideojuegos.php on line 18**

pero si yo hago esto en la funcion:

```
  public function getVideojuegos(){
        $this->con=new Conexion();
        $this->con=$this->con->connect();
        $sql="SELECT * FROM videojuegos";
        $execute=$this->con->query($sql);
        $request=$execute->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($request);

    }
```

todo va de maravilla, es como si mi constructor no funcionara.

Comment: Cuando heredas, ya puedes usar las clases de tu padre. No hace falta que instancies la clase conexión en tu constructor porque ya la estás heredando. O en su defecto, solo deberías llamar `$this->connect();`

Comment: ¿Por qué si ya tu clase accede a la conexión mediante herencia generas una instancia de dicha conexión en el contructor de la segunda clase?

Comment: Gracias, es correcto, funciona así sin instanciar, me confundí por que en un ejercicio que estoy usando de guía usan spl_autoload_register() para incluir los archivos necesarios, y ahí si instancian las variables en el constructor.

Comment: yo creo que tiene que llamar al constructor de la clase padre en el hijo, por que no se llamara automatico, parent::__construct(); [Constructores y destructores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: En primer lugar se aprecia en error de sintaxis en el constructor de tu clase, tienes escrito: `__construstc` y la forma correcta es **`__construct`**. Luego, hacer que `OperVideojuegos` extienda de una conexión a la base de datos es no entender el sentido de la herencia en POO. La herencia no existe para poder usar `$this` con todo lo que se mueva en una clase, sino para diferenciar clases de entidades parecidas que comparten ciertas propiedades y otra no como: `Persona` : > `Empleado`, `Profesor` o `Animal` : > `Ave`:  > `Paloma`, `Gorrion` ... Una pregunta que determina ...

Comment: ... si la herencia es correcta, es la siguiente: ***¿El objeto `Y` es un objeto `X`?*** ¿El `Empleado` es una `Persona`? ¿El `Profesor` es una `Persona`? ¿El `Ave` es un `Animal`? ¿La `Paloma` es un `Ave`? ¿El `Gorrion` es un `Ave`? Vamos a preguntárselo ahora a tu modelo: ¿`OperVideojuegos` es una `Conexion` (a una base de datos)? Si la respuesta es **NO**, `Y` no debería heredar de `X` ... La herencia en POO es un asunto metafísico.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los comentarios he entendido mejor como funciona la herencia, no tengo por que instanciar la conexión, puedo utilizar directamente la variable de la clase padre y a partir de ahí realizar mis operaciones en la base de datos.